# Create a procedure to delete any record from child table when it's not in the parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I delete a record from our app it keeps some records in some of tables I'm looking for some help to figure out how can I create a procedure to delete records from child table where it's been already purged from the parent table?

Comment: Need a lot more information here...  What does your table structure look like?  Can you provide some sample data?  What are queries that you've already attempted?  We can't magically give you an answer without any idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: ever heard of `Foreign key constrains` and `Cascade deletes` ??

Comment: are you looking CASCADE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the answer to your question is known as *existential quantification*.  In SQL it has the form:

```
delete from C where not exists (
    select 1 from P 
    where P.child_key = C.key
)
```

However, you're not supposed to get in that position: it should never be the case that a child has no parent.  The child table should have a foreign key declared that *requires* the existence of the parent.  That way, the parent for the child to be inserted, and the parent *cannot* be deleted while a child referencing it exists.

In the presence of such a foreign key constraint, the only permissible order of events is to delete the children first `where exists` key in parent, and then delete the parent.  For correctness, the two statements should be part of a transaction.

Some of the comments suggest using declarative referential integrity (DRI) to effect deletion of your child rows.  I'm not a fan; I use DRI as a form of constraint, to create rules.  For action on the data, I recommend explicit code, where surprises can be handled more easily at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

It happens in badly organized DB so you need to clean up your data.

```
delete childTable where FK_field not in (
select PK_field from parentTable)
```

To avoid this problem in future create FK constraint in your childTable.